# Encoding numbers

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding

I am a developer using high level languages.  I usually take the lower level details for granted.

I read that standards such as ASCII and Unicode are for character encodings.  A character has to be stored as a number.  Is this the same for numbers? For example, if I declare a variable in .NET like this:

```
dim test as integer=5
```

In this case the value of test (5) will be represented as decimal: 49 according to [this table](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ascii%20table&biw=1164&bih=642&tbm=isch&imgil=OKl_qO0wvr0VjM%253A%253Ba4Yz9EXV9nDq1M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.bibase.com%25252Fascii.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=OKl_qO0wvr0VjM%253A%252Ca4Yz9EXV9nDq1M%252C_&usg=__0eqK-9ezdt13ezgxJmtBQzM95cI%3D&ved=0CDcQyjc&ei=6LlbVZ-4HsPd7Qa5loPgCQ#imgrc=OKl_qO0wvr0VjM%253A%3Ba4Yz9EXV9nDq1M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bibase.com%252Fimages%252Fascii.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bibase.com%252Fascii.htm%3B800%3B448).  Is that correct?

Comment: No.  It will be stored as 00000000000000000000000000000101.  Computers count with 2 fingers, base 10 was a random accident 500 million years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you code `Dim test As String = "5"` the value will be stored using the Unicode encoding for the character "5". However, Integers (and other numeric types) are not strings and are not encoded in that way, they are represented internally using their numeric value. An Integer is stored as a 32 bit value.

Comment: Thanks. The reference to the string data makes sense. I guess the data type is encoded as well.

Comment: @w0051977: The way I look at it is that each datatype has its own way of being represented. In the .Net Framework, characters and strings are represented by the Unicode encoding (there are ways to convert to different encodings, but Unicode is what is used internally). The Integer data type is stored as a 32-bit number (there is a special rule for representing  negative numbers). Floating point and Decimal types have their own representations, etc. Most of the time when programming you just need to know how to use the different data types.

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking about is data representation in memory.The way integers are represented depends on the whether they are signed or unsigned. IF they are signed (usually the case, unless you specify type as unsigned int or something equvalent) they are represented in binary in two's complement form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement